# How to add an DropDown-Control to an Image?

Tags: asp.net, image, drop-down-menu

I wanna have a Setting-Image, only the Image, a random Image, and when a user clicks this, it should display an easy drop down list with 4 settings...

Hwo to do that?

Comment: just like the stack exchange image button on the top left corner of the SO page ?

Comment: Not exactly but nearly :)

Comment: Then what 'exactly' do you want. Your question is pretty vague. Help us help you (with your rep and badges you should know better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this kind feature using jquery. What you can do add a div containing li elements holding the 4 settings. You have to set this div has hidden. Then add an image tag to the page, and handle the click of the image to show the hidden settings div.